# WebGL + Three.js - Applying Custom Texture to .Obj Model

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I've pasted all of my code. Basically, I can't figure out how to apply a custom texture to my object. I would like to apply something like this to my javascript code below, replacing the MeshLambertMaterial but I have no idea where to get started. I feel like it should be no more than a few lines of code. I basically need to replace the following:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
      var material2 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x33ffcc });

      object.traverse( function(child) {
        if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {

          // apply custom material
          child.material = material2;
        }
      });
```

...with something more like this:

```
var texture = new THREE.Texture();

            var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader();
            loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {

                texture.image = event.content;
                texture.needsUpdate = true;
                texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
                texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestMipMapLinearFilter;

            } );
            loader.load( 'texture.png' );
```

The following is my main script:

```
 var my3dview = {
  scene: null,
  camera: null,
  renderer: null,
  container: null,
  controls: null,
  clock: null,

  init: function() { // Initialization

    // create main scene
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2(0xcce0ff, 0.0003);

    var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
    SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

    // prepare camera
    var VIEW_ANGLE = 6, ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR = 1, FAR = 1000;
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
    this.scene.add(this.camera);
    this.camera.position.set(0,50,300);
    this.startPosition = this.camera.position.clone();
    this.camera.position.set(this.startPosition.x, this.startPosition.y, this.startPosition.z);
    this.camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));

    // prepare renderer
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias:true });
    this.renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    this.renderer.setClearColor(this.scene.fog.color);

    // prepare container
    this.container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(this.container);
    this.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

    // events
    THREEx.WindowResize(this.renderer, this.camera);

    // prepare controls (OrbitControls)
    this.controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
    this.controls.target = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    this.controls.maxDistance = 1000;

    // prepare clock
    this.clock = new THREE.Clock();

    // add spot light
    var spLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 1.75, 2000, Math.PI);
    spLight.position.set(200, 1000, 200);

    this.scene.add(spLight);
    // add spot light
    var spLight2 = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 1.75, 2000, Math.PI);
    spLight2.position.set(-200, -750, -200);
    this.scene.add(spLight2);

    // load a model
    this.loadModel();
  },
  loadModel: function() {

    // prepare loader and load the model
    var oLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    oLoader.load('tshirt.obj', function(object, materials) {

      var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
      var material2 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x33ffcc });

      object.traverse( function(child) {
        if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {

          // apply custom material
          child.material = material2;
        }
      });

      object.position.x = 6;
      object.position.y = -8;
      object.position.z = 0;
      object.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
      my3dview.scene.add(object);
    });
  }
};

// Animate the scene
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
  update();
}

// Update controls
function update() {
  my3dview.controls.update(my3dview.clock.getDelta());
}

// Render the scene
function render() {
  if (my3dview.renderer) {
    my3dview.renderer.render(my3dview.scene, my3dview.camera);
  }
}

// Initialize lesson on page load
function initializeLesson() {
  my3dview.init();
  animate();
}

if (window.addEventListener)
  window.addEventListener('load', initializeLesson, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
  window.attachEvent('onload', initializeLesson);
else window.onload = initializeLesson;
```

I'm loading the following files from my main HTML:

```
<script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/OBJLoader.js"></script>
<script src="js/THREEx.WindowResize.js"></script>
<script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="js/stats.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script1.js"></script>
```

Comment: take a look at http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/TextureLoader

Comment: @drearypanoramic Can you put the whole code (with object, texture, etc.) in jsfiddle? It'll be easy to find the problem.

Comment: @MrFreeman555 I would if I knew how to integrate three.js into JSFiddle properly with my 3D object. But as you can see above, I've literally pasted all of my code. My main HTML file consists of nothing but a few script calls. It all works fine, both the object and texture map render, and you can rotate the camera around the object freely. I just don't know how to integrate the custom texture.

Comment: @drearypanoramic Well, there is no sense to put whole code on StackOverFlow, just put it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), files like "tshirt.obj" or some textures put in [Github](http://github.com) as a reference, see example [jsfiddle+github](http://jsfiddle.net/Freeman555/5yszkvkr/1/)